# y combinator and the C preprocessor

Tags: c, functional-programming

As far as I know y combinator is useful if you want to write a recursive function without using recursion explicitly. The C preprocessor does not support recursion. Can we implement the y combinator in C preprocessor in order to support recursion?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a detailed sample where and how you would use the y combinator in actual code, assuming that it was possible to implement it in a C preprocessor? The question you asked only tells us what you are trying to do but not why you want to do it the first place. Maybe whatever you are trying to achieve can be achieved without implementing anything if its just done the right way.

Comment: lambda? not in standard C, the closest is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C_lambda_expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this is completely possible, please see my project [CSP Git Repo](https://github.com/BlueFlo0d/CSP), this is a LISP interpreter COMPLETELY implemented on C macro preprocessor, and of course you can implement Y combinator on it.

Hope you to and some tests/example if you are interested in it.

Here is the most relevant part. (from csp.h)
It successfully implements closure and lambda, which gives support for implementing fixed point combinators.

```
#define EVAL_e(x) x
#define _be(y) y)
#define ZIP(x)   _n() (x,_be

#define _PAIR(x,y) _e( __PAIR(x,y))
#define __PAIR(x,y) _E COND((NULL SAFE_CDR(x)((SAFE_CAR(x) SAFE_CAR(y))))((T)((SAFE_CAR (x) SAFE_CAR (y)) _e(_PAIR2(_e SAFE_CDR(x),_e SAFE_CDR(y))))))

#define _PAIR2(x,y)  _E COND((NULL SAFE_CDR(x)((SAFE_CAR(x) SAFE_CAR(y))))((T)((SAFE_CAR (x) SAFE_CAR (y)) _e(_PAIR3(_e SAFE_CDR(x),_e SAFE_CDR(y))))))

#define _PAIR3(x,y)  _E COND((NULL SAFE_CDR(x)((SAFE_CAR(x) SAFE_CAR(y))))((T)((SAFE_CAR (x) SAFE_CAR (y)) _e(_PAIR4(_e SAFE_CDR(x),_e SAFE_CDR(y))))))

#define _PAIR4(x,y)  _E COND((NULL SAFE_CDR(x)((SAFE_CAR(x) SAFE_CAR(y))))((T)((SAFE_CAR (x) SAFE_CAR (y)) _e(DELAY_INT_54(__PAIR_R) ()(SAFE_CDR(x) SAFE_CDR(y))))))
#define __PAIR_R() _$pair
#define TEST_R() TEST
#define TEST(x) test
#define _PAIR_e(x) x
#define _$pair(x) _PAIR_e(_PAIR ZIP x)
#define PAIR_EVAL(...) PAIR_EVAL2(PAIR_EVAL2(PAIR_EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define PAIR_EVAL2(...) PAIR_EVAL3(PAIR_EVAL3(PAIR_EVAL3(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define PAIR_EVAL3(...) PAIR_EVAL4(PAIR_EVAL4(PAIR_EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define PAIR_EVAL4(...) PAIR_EVAL_E(PAIR_EVAL_E(PAIR_EVAL_E(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define PAIR_EVAL_E(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define $pair(x) PAIR_EVAL(_$pair(x))

#define $zipped_evlis_R() $zipped_evlis
#define EVLIS_e_R() EVLIS_e
#define EVLIS_e(x) x
#define _EVLIS_ZIP(...) _n() (__VA_ARGS__,_BE
#define _BE(...) __VA_ARGS__)
#define _EVLIS_R() _EVLIS
#define _EVLIS_E(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define _EVLIS_N(...)
#define _EVLIS_B _EVLIS_E (_EVLIS_N,_EVLIS_E(_EVLIS_N,_EVLIS_N))
#define ___EVLIS(a,b,k,...) k($zipped_eval((b),(a)) DELAY_INT_2(_EVLIS_R)()(a))
#define __EVLIS(a,b,...) ___EVLIS(a,b,__VA_ARGS__ _EVLIS_E)
#define _EVLIS_EVAL_E(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define _EVLIS_EVAL_5(...) _EVLIS_EVAL_E(_EVLIS_EVAL_E(_EVLIS_EVAL_E(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define _EVLIS_EVAL_4(...) _EVLIS_EVAL_5(_EVLIS_EVAL_5(_EVLIS_EVAL_5(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define _EVLIS_EVAL_3(...) _EVLIS_EVAL_4(_EVLIS_EVAL_4(_EVLIS_EVAL_4(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define _EVLIS_EVAL_2(...) _EVLIS_EVAL_3(_EVLIS_EVAL_3(_EVLIS_EVAL_3(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define _EVLIS_EVAL(...) _EVLIS_EVAL_2(_EVLIS_EVAL_2(_EVLIS_EVAL_2(__VA_ARGS__)))

#define _EVLIS(x) __EVLIS _EVLIS_ZIP(x)
#define $zipped_evlis(x,y) _EVLIS_EVAL(_EVLIS y x (_EVLIS_B))

#define $zipped_eval_R() $zipped_eval
#define $zipped_eval(e,a) /**sth irrelevant**/
        ($eq(SAFE_CAR SAFE_CAR e (lambda))\
        (DELAY_INT_26(EVAL_e_R)() DELAY_INT_23($zipped_eval_R)()(\
        EVAL_e(EVAL_e(EVAL_e(EVAL_e(SAFE_CAR SAFE_CDR SAFE_CDR SAFE_CAR e)))),\
        EVAL_e(APPEND DELAY_INT_13($pair_R)()(EVAL_e(EVAL_e(EVAL_e(SAFE_CAR SAFE_CDR SAFE_CAR e)))\
                                              (DELAY_INT_19($zipped_evlis_R)()(EVAL_e(_e EVAL_e(SAFE_CDR e)), a)))a)))\
        /**end of eval recursion**/

#define $pair_R() $pair
#define EVAL_e_R() EVAL_e
#define $eval_E(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define $eval_expand5(...) $eval_E($eval_E($eval_E(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define $eval_expand4(...) $eval_expand5($eval_expand5($eval_expand5(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define $eval_expand3(...) $eval_expand4($eval_expand4($eval_expand4(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define $eval_expand2(...) $eval_expand3($eval_expand3($eval_expand3(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define $eval_expand(...) $eval_expand2($eval_expand2($eval_expand2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define $zeval(x,y) $eval_expand($zipped_eval(x,y))
```

Comment: Ok I've quote the most important part which implements lambda. It is shown that using FP on CPP is completely possible.

Answer (score 1):

Y combinator is a higher-order function and it needs a higher-order function support in the language to implement an explicit recursion substitution. Therefore, for particular tasks this can be done in Scheme, SML and other functional languages.

Let's talk about C preprocessor later, but what about C itself? It could be possible to use higher order functions in C as we can pass function references as function arguments and return them to emulate higher-order functions. However, the lack of closures support in the language does not allow to implement Y combinator.

As preprocessor is even more restrictive that C, there is no way to implement Y combinator which is based on lambda calculus concepts. The application of Y combinator can be achieved only in functional programming languages with higher-order functions full support.

C preprocessor is very straightforward as it does only string substitution in a text. I would not try to apply any concepts from lambda calculus and functional programming to it.